# Why does the 'access review queues' privilege on MSE require more rep than SO?

Tags: support, meta, privileges

I went through the privileges pages on Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow, and the 'access review queues' privilege requires a lot more rep than SO (2K for MSE, 500 for SO.)

Is this because MSE is considered more important than SO? This may be wrong, but I always thought that they had similar levels of importance and content levels.

Comment: If anything MSE privileges come at lower reputation thresholds. Can you give an example where an SO privilege needs less rep than on MSE?

Comment: Accessing review queues - 500 for SO, 2K for MSE.

Comment: Per our FAQ [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di): *The* First questions, First answers, *and* Late answers *review queues don't exist on Meta Stack Exchange (and all per-site metas), so on Meta Stack Exchange, the minimum requirement to access any review queue is 2,000. (For this reason, the privilege page on this site states that 2,000 is the minimum requirement.)*